# « Basculer les heures »

Tags: usage, verbes

En parlant de l'emploi de temps, j'ai entendu un collègue dire :

> Basculons les heures (d'enseignement).

voulant dire (je crois) changer/échanger les heures.

Larousse n'a pas cette signification (?) du verbe basculer

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/basculer/8179

Selon

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/basculer

la seule signification proche que je vois c'est osciller. Qu'est-ce que je ne comprends pas ?

Comment: Are you sure they didn't use "bousculons"?  That could mean "Let's shake things [class times] up a bit! "

Comment: Tu n'as pas entendu plus de la phrase ? Sans plus de contexte, c'est ambigu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Basculer** : *Opérer un renversement brusque de ses positions; changer brutalement d'orientation, de direction.*

In this context, **basculer** means : **reschedule**. (reschedule brutally because, something happened that was not expected.)

**Exemple** : *Le professeur n'est pas là. On devrait basculer ses heures de cours le lundi matin.* / 
*The teacher is not here. We should reschedule his class hours on Monday morning.*

Comment: Je ne suis pas vraiment sûr de cela. À mon sens *basculer* est utilisé au sens de **réaffecter, réallouer.**

Comment: @aCOSwt Sans le contexte, je ne vois pas ce qui permettrait de pencher plus pour l'un ou l'autre.

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit d'une expression imagée.

Imaginez une balançoire à bascule: ce qui est en haut vient en bas, ce qui est en bas vient en haut.

Cela revient à *échanger* les heures, à les permuter.